# Number of ways in which 4 letter words can formed by using the letters from the set-a,a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,d

Tags: permutations

I thought of solving this question by making cases:

1) All four are same

2) 2 are same,2 are distinct

3) 3 are same ,1 is distinct

4) All are distinct

My difficulty is about how to select identical numbers

Like for case 2.How will I choose between-a,a,a, b,b, and c,c for 2 same numbers

Can somebody tell me about this

Comment: You have to count all of them.  Three ways to choose the duplicated letter.

Comment: I am still not getting it....sorry

Comment: Yes, I was a bit telegraphic.  We have have aabc or abbc or abcc as the  ways to have one duplicated letter.  There are $4!/2! = 12$ ways to make a word from one of them, so $3\cdot 12=36$ ways in all.  Attack  the other cases in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The five partitions of $4$ are

- 1+1+1+1,
- 2+1+1,
- 2+2,
- 3+1, and
- 4.

So, if you want to do it this way, you're still missing a case.  It can be done this way though, with careful bookkeeping.

Partition 1+1+1+1: We must have `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` in some order: $4!=24$ ways.

Partition 2+1+1: We have two copies of one letter from `a`, `b`, or `c`, and choose two other letters to write uniquely, and once these letters are chosen we can write it in $4!/2$ ways (we divide by $2$ since if we count all $4!$ permutations, we count each twice when we swap the two identical letters): $3 \times \binom{3}{2} \times 4!/2=108$ ways.

Partition 2+2: We choose two letters from `a`, `b`, or `c`, and we can write them in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways: total $\binom{3}{2} \times \binom{4}{2}=18$ ways.

Partition 3+1: We have three copies of one letter from `a` or `b`, and choose one other letter to write uniquely, and once the letters are chosen, we can write it in $4$ ways: $2 \times \binom{3}{1} \times 4=24$ ways.

Partition 4: We write `aaaa`: $1$ way.

Totaling:
$$
24+108+18+24+1=175
$$
ways.

We can check this by generating them with the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code:

```
Q:=Filtered(Tuples([1..4],4),T->ForAll([1..4],i->Number(T,t->t=i)<=i));
```

And `Size(Q);` returns `175`.

Comment: For partition 1+1+1+1 case,is it valid to say that for selecting an "a",we have 4C1 choice,for "b" 3C1  choice and so on and then arranging them like you stated

Comment: No.  Since the `a`'s are identical, when we choose one `a` from a collection of 4 `a`'s, there's only one possible outcome: one `a`.

Comment: This clears things up.Thanks

Comment: Also when we are selecting the other 2 letters for the above partion then also the repeating identical letters are considered as only one single letter.........I thought over this for some time but I couldn't come up with an explanation for this result.Can you help with this result also